# Python Keras Image reshape not reshaping correctly

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

My model is trained on the [cifar10 dataset](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html)

My convolution layer is expecting 32, 32 input which is **(None, 3, 32, 32)** for a numpy array.
But when I'm trying to reshape the image

> image = load_img(args["image"], target_size = inputShape)

I'm getting a shape of **(1, 32, 32, 3)**. So what is happening?

This code is largely based on this [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/20/imagenet-vggnet-resnet-inception-xception-keras/).

```
from keras.models
import load_model
from keras.applications
import imagenet_utils
from keras.preprocessing.image
import img_to_array, load_img
from keras
import backend as K
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required = True,
  help = "Path tp the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

inputShape = (32, 32)
preprocess = imagenet_utils.preprocess_input

model = load_model('cifar.h5')
print("[INFO]: loading and pre-processing image...")
image = load_img(args["image"], target_size = inputShape)
image = image_to_array(image)
print image.shape

image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)

image = preprocess(image)

print("[INFO]: classifying image")
preds = model.predict(image)
P = imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(preds)

for (i, (imagenetID, label, prob)) in enumerate(P[0]):
    (imagenetID, label, prob) = P[0][0]
    print("{}. {}: {:.2f}%".format(i + 1, label, prob * 100))

orig = cv2.imread(args["image"])
cv2.putText(orig, "Label: {}, {:.2f}%".format(label, prob * 100), (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Classification", orig)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add line

```
image = image.copy().transpose((2,0,1))
```

after `image = image_to_array(image)` line